# Best way to call an initator flow that is overriden in another cordapp

Tags: corda

Apologies in advance for the basic question and please ignore the mix of kotlin/java!

I’ve spun up a very simple example building upon the example-cordapp and I wish to demonstrate the ability to override flows to put in some additional node operator specific logic from another cordapp.  For example: a certain node owner may not want to do business under certain scenarios, so add in some additional checks prior to the initiating or responder signing phase.

I’ve successfully overridden the responder flow fine and I can see it being executed on the node with the extending cordapp however I’m not having much luck with initiator flow.

From reading here: https://www.corda.net/blog/extending-and-overriding-flows-from-external-cordapps/ it suggests that I would have to have my api/rpc client directly invoke the extended version directly, however I was hoping it would work similar to the responder flow and automatically pick it up based on the hops.

Base flow:

```
public class BondFlow {
    @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    public static class Initiator extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
    // Stuff
        public Initiator(int bondValue, Party obligee, Party principal) {
            this.bondValue = bondValue;
            this.obligee = obligee;
            this.principal = principal;
        }
    // More Stuff
```

Overridden (in a separate Cordapp):

```
public class MyCustomFlow {
    @StartableByRPC
    public static class Initiator extends BondFlow.Initiator {
    // Stuff
        public Initiator(int bondValue, Party obligee, Party principal) {
            super(bondValue, obligee, principal);
        }
    // More stuff
```

My RPC client just calls the Initiator as you may expect:

```
val signedTx = proxy.startTrackedFlow(::Initiator, bondValue, obligeeParty, principalParty).returnValue.getOrThrow()
```

I could change my api/rpc client call to allow configuration of the initiator flow to be called but I'd like to understand if there is an alternative.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly suggest that you give flows different names for each different flows. We had named a couple of our flows simple as `initiator` and `responder` out of the simplicity purpose.

However, it is still fine to have same names cross different CorDapps. You just need to call their full name including the package name.

Run `flow list` in your node shell and you should see it.

For example:

our signature YoFlow in the yo-Cordapp has a full name of `net.corda.examples.yo.flows.YoFlow,`
but in single cordapp scenario, you can just call it by run `flow start YoFlow`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter, renaming is no problem, I'm really at the experimentation stage.  In my experience a cordapp is usually released with a separate rest api for interoperability for users.  So really I'm looking for ways to design the API to support flow extension, at the moment to do this, I think i'm probably looking at using config properties and reflection but was hoping for something a bit more elegant or in built if it was there e.g. flowoverrides or hop based selection.